# Alter section of URL using htaccess

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to alter a part of an URL as below from this type URL ...

```
/shop/product/41/3030651/Apple-Imac-215-Inches-Me086ba-By-Viking.html
```

to this ..

```
/shop/product/1/030651/Apple-Imac-215-Inches-Me086ba-By-Viking.html
```

where all numbers like 41 are altered to 1 but it seems this code ...

```
RewriteRule ^product/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)\.html$ index.php?case=product&proddb=$1&pid=$2&urltxt=$3 [L]
```

is interfering.

I've tried lots of rewrite configurations but nothing seems to work but I do get a reaction from the code below ...

```
RedirectMatch 301 /shop/product/41/(.*) /shop/product/1/$1
```

But it must conflict with the RewriteRule above as I get sent to the root of the site.

Comment: Is `3030651` also becoming `030651`?

Comment: Not that I'm aware as I can't see the URL as I get sent to the root of the site ... /shop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have redirect rule before your earlier rewrite rule:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^product/41/(.+)$ /product/1/$1 [L,NC,R=301]

RewriteRule ^product/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)\.html$ index.php?case=product&proddb=$1&pid=$2&urltxt=$3 [L,QSA,NC]
```

Comment: It does look like the above is working.  I will test further and see.